# eslint and package.json configuration

Tags: eslint, package.json

I have eslint in my project and some rules.
In my package.json I have:

`"lint": "eslint . --ext .js --ext .ts --ext .tsx --ignore-pattern 'node_modules/'"`.

Is there any way to set up extensions which i want to check in **.eslintrc.json** so in package.json i just set:

`"lint": "eslint"`?

package.json

```
{
  "lint": "eslint . --ext .js --ext .ts --ext .tsx --ignore-pattern 'node_modules/'"
}
```

I want to have:

paxkage.json

```
  "lint": "eslint"
```

Answer (score 7):

I am afraid, that putting both parameters to a configuration file as you want them - file extensions to check and a directory pattern to ignore - is currently not possible. File extensions or files to check can be provided only on the command line, as [documented](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-file-extensions-to-lint) and stated [here](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/2274#issuecomment-344996310) and [here](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/1674#issuecomment-70533404).

You can leave the file extensions parameter on the command-line and shorten the command using commas:

```
eslint --ext .js,.ts,.tsx .
```

and move just the `--ignore-pattern` parameter to the `.eslintignore` file, which is a [documented way how to exclude files and directories by multiple patterns](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#ignoring-files-and-directories). For example, `.eslintignore` for a simple JavaScript project:

```
# lcov web site
coverage
# bundled and minified output
dist
# external dependencies
node_modules
```

Patterns to ignore can be put to the `package.json` file too. Use the `eslintIgnore` key similarly to the `eslintConfig` key:

```
"eslintIgnore": [
  "coverage", "dist", "node_modules"
]
```

Alternatively, you could try specifying [all input files in the command-line](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface) using the glob pattern. Use single or double quotes to prevent the shell glob-pattern expansion:

```
eslint "**/*.{js,jsx,es6}"
```

And then specify the patterns to ignore using one of the two ways mentioned above to avoid checking other files than your sources.

Comment: I will use .eslintignore file princip. Thanks for the comment!